# Any easy way to highlight a block of code and insert curly braces before and after?

Tags: netbeans, curly-braces

I saw a couple questions similar to mine, but with different ides (vs, and eclipse).
So, I often find myself wanting to take a block of code and put it inside some sort of repetition statement. Is there an easy way to highlight a block of code using some sort of shortcut that i don't know about to insert curly braces before and after the selected code without **messing up the formatting**?

I currently know two ways to do it, but the both mess up the formatting and so i have to go and indent each line to make it look neater.
The first way is by simply adding my statement and an opening brace before the block, and adding a closing brace after the block. This results in me having to go through each line and tabbing once to indent it. The other way is by cutting the code, adding my statement, adding the both braces, and pasting inside the braces, but that also messes up the formatting and I have to indent it all again.

Original code:

```
    Palindrome test = new Palindrome(word);
    if (test.isPalindrome())
        System.out.printf("'%s' is a palindrome!%n", word);
    else
        System.out.printf("'%s' is not a palindrome!%n", word);
    System.out.print("Enter a word or an integer(case sensitive) or 
        '0' to exit: ");
    word = input.nextLine();
```

first way: (adding statment and opeing brace before code and closing brace after)

```
    while (word != "0")
    {
    Palindrome test = new Palindrome(word);
    if (test.isPalindrome())
        System.out.printf("'%s' is a palindrome!%n", word);
    else
        System.out.printf("'%s' is not a palindrome!%n", word);
    System.out.print("Enter a word or an integer(case sensitive) or '0' to 
        exit: ");
    word = input.nextLine();
    }
```

second way: (cutting code and pasting inside my new statment)

```
    while (word != "0")
    {
        Palindrome test = new Palindrome(word);
    if (test.isPalindrome())
        System.out.printf("'%s' is a palindrome!%n", word);
    else
        System.out.printf("'%s' is not a palindrome!%n", word);
    System.out.print("Enter a word or an integer(case sensitive) or '0' to 
        exit: ");
    word = input.nextLine();
    }
```

After indenting each line:

```
    while (word != "0")
    {
        Palindrome test = new Palindrome(word);
        if (test.isPalindrome())
            System.out.printf("'%s' is a palindrome!%n", word);
        else
            System.out.printf("'%s' is not a palindrome!%n", word);
        System.out.print("Enter a word or an integer(case sensitive) or 
            '0' to exit: ");
        word = input.nextLine();
    }
```

So basically, is there any easy way to go from the original code to the last code without the formatting getting messed up?
(I put it in tags, but I'm using netbeans)

Comment: `ALT-SHIFT-F` will automatically reformat Java source, including correct indentation. It will either reformat the selected text, or the entire file if no text is selected. You can also change the formatting rules if you don't like the default settings: **Tools > Options > Editor**, then select the **Formatting** tab. You shouldn't ever need to manually format Java source in NetBeans.

Comment: @skomisa that works good enough for me. Thanks!

Comment: OK. You can also get NetBeans to automatically reformat your file whenever it is saved, so you don't even need to use `ALT-SHIFT-F`. To do that: **Tools > Options > Editor**, then select the **On Save** tab. From there you can specify the language(s) for which you want automatic reformatting to be done whenever you save a file.